# Please explain usage of "item" in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I found some AWS Ansible code using word `"{{ item.id }}"` or `{{ item.sg_name }}`.

I do not understand how "item" command works.

Answer (score 15):

`item` is not a command, but a variable automatically created and populated by Ansible in tasks which use [loops](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html).

In the following example:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - first
    - second
```

the task will be run twice: first time with the variable `item` set to `first`, the second time with `second`.

Further, if elements of the loop were dictionaries, you could refer to their keys using the dot notation as in your example:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.my_value }}"
  with_items:
    - ny_element: first
      my_value: 1
    - my_element: second
      my_value: 2
```